How to update default customer payment method with API?
I can't find the good method de update Default Customer Payment Method with API :

The PUT is : https://localhost/XXXXXXX/entity/Default/20.200.001/Customer/?$expand=PaymentInstructions
The body sent :
    {
           
      "id": "d9f39ef9-fc6b-ee11-a81d-6045bd6d244f",
         "PmtMethod": {
        "value": "VCFON"
    },
           "PaymentInstructions": [
        {
            "id": "90871690-87eb-ee11-a822-6045bd6d244f"
          
        }
    ]    
          
    }

The first Id is the CustomerId. The second Id is the specific customer payment method I need to put as default customer payment method.
I have a 200 OK but without any modification.

You can extend the Default endpoint and you can add the PaymentMethods entity to it:


I only added these three fields, but you can add more if you need.
You can call it something like this:


Standard endpoint functionality in Acumatica does not support changing the CustomerPaymentMethodInfo class.
I recommend creating a WebHook and using it as an endpoint to change the default payment method, to do this:
Create a new customization -> place the webhook in the Code section -> save and publish the customization;
Then go to the SM304000 screen and generate a new webhook (for it, select the webhook you created);
Then the situation is exactly the same as with endpoints, just create a request with the URL of your endpoint and use the specified parameters.
Example:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PX.Api.Webhooks;
using PX.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using static PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
namespace WebHooks
{
    public class EditDefaultPMWebHook : IWebhookHandler
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    public async Task HandleAsync(WebhookContext context, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        CustomerPaymentMethodRequest customerPaymentMethodRequest;
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(context.Request.CreateTextReader()))
        {
            customerPaymentMethodRequest = Serializer.Deserialize<CustomerPaymentMethodRequest>(reader);
        }
        var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
        var graphExt = graph.GetExtension<PaymentDetailsExt>();
        graph.CurrentCustomer.Current = SelectFrom<Customer>.Where<Customer.acctCD.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.Select(graph, customerPaymentMethodRequest.CustomerID).TopFirst;
        var pms = graphExt.PaymentMethods.Select().FirstTableItems;
        var defaultPM = pms.Where(p => p.IsDefault.GetValueOrDefault(false)).FirstOrDefault();
        defaultPM.IsDefault = false;
        var editablePM = pms.Where(p => p.PaymentMethodID == customerPaymentMethodRequest.PaymentMethodID).FirstOrDefault();
        editablePM.IsDefault = true;
        graphExt.PaymentMethods.Update(defaultPM);
        graphExt.PaymentMethods.Update(editablePM);
        graph.Persist();
        using (var writer = context.Response.CreateTextWriter())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(writer, new { answer = "Default Payment Method is successfully changed" });
        }
    }
}
public class CustomerPaymentMethodRequest
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMethodID { get; set; }
}  

Example url: https://localhost/24R1/Webhooks/Company/8a476e8a-3f88-4a2a-ac8a-e1c138a5fe81  Post {CustomerID = "AACustomer", PaymentMethodID="CASH" }
P.S. this is just example, I didn't test this code as of yet
